# XAML Path control behavior on WP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a Windows 8.1 project WP + WinStore

The button is placed in a cell of Grid, where there is 2 rows and 2 columns. 1 row and 1 column size is 45px. So the toggle button is square.

I have such code to create burger button:

```
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="8" Style="{StaticResource BurgerMenuButtonStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Path VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="White" Data="M1E-06,19.102 L32,19.102 L32,23.878 L1E-06,23.878 z M0,9.553 L32,9.553 L32,14.328 L0,14.328 z M0,0 L32,0 L32,4.775 L0,4.775 z" />
</ToggleButton>
```

The tablet displays the control like this ( which is correct ):

[image]

But windows phone displays like this ( which is incorrect ):

[image]

Could someone suggest a fix and explain why this is hapenning?

Comment: I test your code on Lumia 830 device (1607) but it works well. So what's your Windows Phone type and the OS version? And how about the `BurgerMenuButtonStyle`?

Comment: @Mattew Wu i have found the issue. It seems that control styles for tablet and phone are different, what caused a normal behavior on tablet and not normal on phone